# Powershell variable preceded by = does not evaluate

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm writing some PowerShell scripts to work with our source control software (which is not a PowerShell cmdlet) and I'm running into a problem using variables as command line arguments when they are preceded by an `=`, like this:

```
cm mklabel lb:BL$baseline -c=$comment
```

This ends up create a label in with the comment of "$comment".  If I put a space after the `=`, it looks like it evaluates the variable properly, but the command does not associate the comment with `-c` argument anymore.  Is there a way to force the variable to be evaluated despite the `=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cm mklabel lb:BL$baseline -c=($comment)
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple like that, thanks!

Comment: @Ajj Both, excited to get the answer, frustrated that it wasn't easier to find. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cm mklabel lb:BL$baseline "-c=$comment"
```

Comment: That might work, but the `$comment` itself contains quotes, so I think that causes issues.